# SharePoint 365 - Get user name based on user id returned from api to separate list

Tags: sharepoint

I'm getting a user id number back when I API a person field on a list.  I'm hoping someone knows of an easy way to get the user name value for a particular user id.

My goal is to populate a person field in my current list form with a value from a person field in another list based on certain conditions, but unfortunately I'm not sure how to utilize the user id toward this end.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.  Instead of using a people picker I used an ASP textbox and databind to update to the user id.  Appears to work.